# How to handle the cache per user in REST Resource?

Tags: caching, 8, meta-tags, http-request

I have a requirement to expose a specific content type data via REST end point. Below is my code:

```
public function get() {
    $current_user = $this->currentUser->id();
    $user = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('user')->load($current_user);
    $userLangId = $user->language()->getId();

    // You must to implement the logic of your REST Resource here.
    // Use current user after pass authentication to validate access.
    if (!$this->currentUser->hasPermission('access content')) {
      throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();
    }
    $news_values = [
      'langcode' => $userLangId,
      'type' => ['story'],
      'status' => 1,
    ];
    $news_data = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node')->loadByProperties($news_values);
    $newsfeed = [];
    $newsfeed['stories'] = ['Story' => array_values($news_data)];
    if (empty($newsfeed)) {
      return new ResourceResponse('No Newsfeed exist for this user.', 400);
    }
    $response = new ResourceResponse($newsfeed, 200);
//    $response->addCacheableDependency($current_user);

    $response->addCacheableDependency(CacheableMetadata::createFromRenderArray([
      '#cache' => [
        'context' => ['user.roles'],
        'tags' => ['user:3', 'languages:' . $userLangId],
      ],
    ]));
    return $response;
  }
```

I am getting a proper response with this but I am facing issues in handling the cache.
This content is user specific. Based on user language content will popup when they access.

In Response Headers I am getting below things:

```
X-Drupal-Cache-Contexts: languages:language_interface theme url.site user.permissions
X-Drupal-Cache-Tags: config:filter.format.basic_html config:rest.resource.newsfeed_rest_resource config:rest.settings config:system.site http_response languages:fr node:7 node:9 user:3
X-Drupal-Dynamic-Cache: MISS/HIT
```

In Cache-tags i have not added node key but its automatically coming and its working once node updated. But if i try to login with different user via `basic auth` on postman client, content is not changing at all. Its showing cached content for previous user. How I can cache the content per user. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Looks like your cache context is by the users role. Is that what you want? As if 2 of your users have the same roles so they'd get the same cached response

Comment: Ohh right. But how I can make it user specific instead of roles or permissions?

Comment: Just change `['user.roles']` to `['user']` and clear your caches should work

Comment: Its not working. As i can see in this article https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-contexts there is no ['user'] context.

Comment: When i changed the weight for USER in Detection and selection in language interface. It started working without cache context.

Comment: This makes sense because then the page language depends on the user and the language detection needs to bubble up the `user` context to the page.

Answer (score 3):

@Leigh is right and `user` does exist. Cache contexts are hierarchical (see change record https://www.drupal.org/node/2451661) and `user` is a top level context.

So this should work (note the plural form of `contexts`):

```
  '#cache' => [
    'contexts' => ['user'],
```

You can also add the cache context by IDE autocompleting:

```
$response->getCacheableMetadata()->addCacheContexts(['user']);
```

Comment: Hey @4k4, Thanks for your detailed explanation. When i add above line, X-Drupal-Dynamic-Cache: UNCACHEABLE. Is it caching or not?

Comment: The response might be not cacheable for a different reason, which could be for example the line you have commented out. $current_user is not a cacheable object, then Drupal doesn't raise an error, it silently adds a cache max age of 0 as fallback.